# Как вывести меню в SystemTrayIcon?

Tags: c++, qt

Как вывести меню в SystemTrayIcon? Мне нужно чтобы программа стала невидимой, появилась иконка и работал метод с функцией Sleep(). А когда пользователю захочется закончить программу, одним нажатием правой кнопки мыши на иконку, появлением меню с действием "Выйти" он смог выйти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование стандартного `Qt`:

- После запуска, появится иконка с указанной картинкой и всплывающей подсказкой.
- При нажатии правой кнопкой на нее появится меню.
- Если кликать на иконку трея левой кнопкой мышки, окно программы будет скрываться/показываться.

**h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    private slots:
        void messageReceived(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason);

    private:
        QSystemTrayIcon tray;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMenu>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    tray.setIcon(QIcon(":/app_icon"));
    tray.setToolTip("Tray!");

    connect(&tray, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), SLOT(messageReceived(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

    QMenu * trayMenu = new QMenu();
    trayMenu->addAction("Show");
    trayMenu->addSeparator();
    trayMenu->addAction("About");
    trayMenu->addSeparator();
    trayMenu->addAction("Quit");

    tray.setContextMenu(trayMenu);
    tray.show();
}

void MainWindow::messageReceived(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    if (reason == QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger) {
        setVisible(!isVisible());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться готовым классом TrayMenu https://github.com/sashatref/TrayMenu

TrayMenu.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMainWindow>

class TrayMenu : public QSystemTrayIcon
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TrayMenu(QMainWindow *mainWindow, const QIcon &_icon = QIcon());
    virtual ~TrayMenu();

    void addAction(QAction *_action);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private slots:
    void onExitMenuClicked();
    void onMaximizeMenuClicked();
    void onTrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason _reason);

private:
    QMap<int, QAction*> m_actionList;

    QMenu *m_menu;
    QAction *m_exitAction;
    QAction *m_maximizeAction;
    QMainWindow *m_mainWindow;

    QByteArray m_state;
    void showMainWindow();
    void retranslate();
};
```

TrayMenu.cpp

```
#include "traymenu.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QEvent>


TrayMenu::TrayMenu(QMainWindow *mainWindow, const QIcon &_icon):
    QSystemTrayIcon(mainWindow),
    m_menu(new QMenu()),
    m_mainWindow(mainWindow)
{
    QSystemTrayIcon::setIcon(_icon);
    this->setContextMenu(m_menu);
    m_exitAction = new QAction(tr("Выход"), m_menu);
    m_maximizeAction = new QAction(tr("Показать"), m_menu);

    m_menu->addAction(m_maximizeAction);
    m_menu->addSeparator();
    m_menu->addAction(m_exitAction);
    m_menu->addSeparator();

    connect(m_exitAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &TrayMenu::onExitMenuClicked);
    connect(m_maximizeAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &TrayMenu::onMaximizeMenuClicked);
    connect(this, &TrayMenu::activated, this, &TrayMenu::onTrayActivated);

    m_mainWindow->installEventFilter(this);
    setToolTip(m_mainWindow->windowTitle());
}

TrayMenu::~TrayMenu()
{
    m_mainWindow->removeEventFilter(this);
    delete m_maximizeAction;
    delete m_exitAction;
    delete m_menu;
}

void TrayMenu::addAction(QAction *_action)
{
    m_menu->insertAction(m_maximizeAction, _action);
}

bool TrayMenu::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == m_mainWindow && event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
    {
        if(m_mainWindow->isMinimized())
        {
            this->show();
            m_state = m_mainWindow->saveState();
            m_mainWindow->hide();
        }
    } else if(obj == m_mainWindow && event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
        retranslate();
    }

    return m_mainWindow->eventFilter(obj, event);
}

void TrayMenu::onExitMenuClicked()
{
    m_mainWindow->close();
}

void TrayMenu::onMaximizeMenuClicked()
{
    showMainWindow();
}


void TrayMenu::onTrayActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason _reason)
{
    if(_reason == QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger)
    {
        showMainWindow();
    }
}

void TrayMenu::showMainWindow()
{
    this->hide();
    m_mainWindow->show();
    m_mainWindow->setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive);
    m_mainWindow->restoreState(m_state);
}

void TrayMenu::retranslate()
{
    m_exitAction->setText(tr("Выход"));
    m_maximizeAction->setText(tr("Показать"));
}
```

И минимальный пример использования:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    TrayMenu *trayMenu = new TrayMenu(this, QIcon(":/images/472785-appicns_Word.png"));

    QAction *myCustomAction = new QAction(tr("Показать Msg"), this);
    connect(myCustomAction, &QAction::triggered, this, [trayMenu]()
    {
        trayMenu->showMessage("Title", "Msg");
    });

    trayMenu->addAction(myCustomAction);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Или посмотреть внутри как оно реализовано и адаптировать под себя.

1. Создать экземпляр QSystemTrayIcon и установить для него картинку setIcon
2. Создать QMenu и установить его для QSystemTrayIcon: setContextMenu(menu);
3. Создать нужные QAction, добавить их в QMenu и повесить на них нужные события.
4. Подписаться на события изменения состояния окна программы, при сворачивание программы - прятать его с панели задач и показывать QSystemTrayIcon